# Pandas Select Columns with simple operations

Tags: python, pandas

The idea is to select two columns from a DataFrame, but one of the columns needs to be divided by 2. I have the following code :

```
C = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','B','C'], 'num1': [99,3,5], 'num2' :[3.5,99,-5]})
C['num1_aux'] = C.num1/2
C['final'] = C[['num1_aux','num2']].min(axis=1)
```

Which gives me the result. 
I would like to know how would it be possible withou the auxiliary step, so including the operation in the selection. Which would be something like:

```
C['final'] = C[[C.num1/2,C.num2]].min(axis=1)
```

Which returns the error :

> KeyError: "None of [Index([(49.5, 1.5, 2.5), (3.5, 99.0, -5.0)], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

The operation works : `(49.5, 1.5, 2.5)`. But the application is off. If possible a way to find this in the Pandas documentation to avoid these simple (or dumb) questions here would be nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [.assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```
C['final'] = C.assign(num1_aux=C['num1']/2)[['num1_aux','num2']].min(1)
```

Output:

```
    name    num1    num2    final
0   A        99      3.5    3.5
1   B         3     99.0    1.5
2   C         5     -5.0    -5.0
```